# How to export a component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am a newbie in `reactjs`. I want to export a component into another component. I want to export this `name_of_the_component` from helper component into.

Below is the code snippet

```js
class Helper extends React.Component {

    render = () => {
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(
           ............
        );
    };
} 

export function error(Component) {

        return (
            ......
        );
    };
}

export default class Maincomponent extends React.Component {
     render{
         return (
             ......
         );
     }
}
```

I want to export the function named error from helper component into Maincomponent. I tried using import error from helper 
export default class error. This throws error cannot use export default module more than once. Could someone help me with this.

Comment: Would you add a code snippet for your `import` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import { error } from '../path/to/file'`

Parenthesis `{ }` for non-default exports. No parenthesis for default exports.

Answer (score 0):

You can also, create a stateless component. Then import the error function wherever you want. Just like Joey, mentioned above..